# Cocos2dx CCEditBox Extension declaration error

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I want to use CCEditBox and I added USING_NS_CC_EXT; and using namespace cocos2d::extension;.
But I am getting following error.

```
jni/../../Classes/LoginLayer.cpp:92:2: error: 'CCEditbox' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/LoginLayer.cpp:92:13: error: 'm_pEditName' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../Classes/LoginLayer.cpp:92:45: error: 'editBoxSize' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 0):

you shoud to include extentions header file:

```
#include "cocos-ext.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

if your error wont be solved after include then use 
USING_NS_CC::extension;
after your name space.
 thank you